# Error with Mapbox GL integration when adding markers: "Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker, webflow

I've been working on creating a dynamically updated Mapbox GL integration inside Webflow's CMS. I've succeeded in creating an array of features that can be read by Mapbox's API, but these features won't show on the map because the coordinates are not being read by the function that creates the map markers.

I receive the following error `Cannot read property 'coordinates' of undefined at map-test-page:139` which is where a longitude and latitude is assigned to the current marker via this line: `.setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)`

Partial solution was found [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1943), but the code I've integrated into my site doesn't have `featuresIn` or `featuresAt` functions which seem to be the only way to include a `includeGeometry: true` parameter.

I'm curious if I need to rethink how I've created markers and do something with a function like `map.on('click', ...)` [reference here](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/4906b495e0b206758f71).

Here is a [minimal version that reproduces my issue](https://beyond-good.webflow.io/map-test-page).

If you're familiar with the Webflow interface you can view a [read-only version of the site](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/beyond-good?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=beyond-good&preview=0698ac095d63f4183817896b7dcc76d8&pageId=61083c9cf0905910c55d1ae6&workflow=preview).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the Mapbox script I'm using on the page:

```
 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/strawpari/ckp2nu3dw6cwu17nt4kqwf1vv',
    center: [-13.723969, 48.360542],
        zoom: 2,
        pitch: 0,
        bearing: 0,
        antialias: true,
        interactive: true
  });

var geojson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: farmerArray,
};

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
    .setHTML('<img src=\'' + marker.properties.image + '\' width=\'50\' height=\'50\' border-radius=\'50%\'>' + '<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>'))
    .addTo(map);
});
```

And here is the code embedded in each CMS item that adds a farmer's information to the farmerArray which is being read by Mapbox. Text in double-quotations "" is a placeholder for the dynamic information populated by the CMS.

```
var farmerArrayItem = 
JSON.stringify({
   type: 'Feature',
   geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: ["longitude", "latitude"]
   },
   properties: {
      title: "name",
      description: "text",
      image: "imagepath"
  }
});

farmerArray.push(farmerArrayItem);
```

Comment: Please include a minimal version reproducing your issue.

Comment: Thank you @SteveBennett, minimal version has been added.

Comment: Ideally you should include the code here, and also in a codepen, to make it as easy as possible for people to assist you.

Comment: @SteveBennett thank you for the advice! Code has been added, but not in codepen because the issue is partially caused by the dynamic CMS item which is only in Webflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you have tried using the Developer Tools to debug your code. That's definitely a skill you should pick up.

With the dev tools, you will quickly see that the value of `marker` at the critical point is a string:

[image]

So you just need to use JSON.parse:

```js
geojson.features.forEach(function(markerString) {
  const marker = JSON.parse(markerString);

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I implemented this and it works perfectly. I appreciate your patience and help—I'm a beginner with JS and Mapbox so this was really helpful.